# Boost Serializer: getting warning C4308 unless using virtual class destructor

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm working on a project which has 2 classes (relevant to my question) that need to be serialized. For a while, one of the classes compiled fine and the other compiled with the following warning:

```
...\boost\mpl\print.hpp(51): warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type
```

For both of them, I was using the Boost class exporter to register the classes so later on I could safely serialize base class pointers to instances of them, like this:

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(ClassName, "ClassName")
```

So I slowly eliminated differences between the two classes and found that the source of the warning was this: the class that compiled quietly had a virtual destructor, since I was planning on having other classes inherit from it that might need their own destructors.

For now, I just gave the other class a virtual destructor as well, but since I don't plan on inheriting from it, this seems weird.

My question is: why does giving the class a virtual destructor "fix" this warning, and what does the warning really mean? Is some part of the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID macro creating a class that inherits from my class or something?

Answer (score 3):

I just posted this question, but I think I might have just realized at least part of the solution.

The BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID macro is meant to "register" a class that will inherit from a base class, in the case that a structure containing base class pointers to instances of the child class needs to be serialized, so that the serializer can distinguish between the types of pointers like

```
BaseClass* base;// = new BaseClass()
BaseClass* derived;// = new DerivedClass()
```

without casting them explicitly, for the sake of polymorphism.

And in the case that a class is going to be inherited, (I think) it is safest to give it a virtual destructor so that the derived classes can clean up after themselves.

HOWEVER: I was not planning on inheriting from the class which was having trouble compiling, and so there was no point in exporting it with BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID. So I was receiving the warning for bad practice - you should not export classes from which you won't inherit later.